# how to set EnabledProtocols with IISAdministration module

Tags: powershell, iis

this works

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$site_name" -name EnabledProtocols -Value "http,net.tcp"
```

but how/can I do this with the IISAdministration commands?

Edit:

what I've tried. Note that it appears to make no actual change as closing and re-opening ps shows EnabledProtocols = 'http'
[image]

The Solution as pointed out by LexLi:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Module IISAdministration
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $site = Get-IISSite
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $site.Applications[0].EnabledProtocols
http
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $site.Applications[0].EnabledProtocols = 'htp,net.tcp'
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $sm = Get-IISServerManager
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $sm.CommitChanges()
```

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.commitchanges?view=iis-dotnet)

Comment: Get the root application of that site first, and then set the property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/#attributes

Comment: @LexLi I've edited the question with a screenshot. Am I doing this wrong? I've tried that but I see no change in IIS Advanced Properties dialog and when I close and re-open poweshell it is still set to http only.

Comment: Please apply your changes.

Comment: @LexLi damn dude :) I just logged out of the windows partition... do you mean ServerManager.CommitChanges ?... before I pop back into windows

Comment: @LexLi That was the solution. Add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from comments.

The Microsoft article shows how to change properties of `Application` via C#,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/#attributes

IISAdministration cmdlets help to mimic the same in PowerShell, so after setting the value of that property, you also need to call `CommitChanges`.